# Can't get in recovery or normal boot HTC One M7

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, bootloader, htc

**Please help me.**

I've done something really stupid. I flashed from ClockWorkMod to Android Revolution HD on my HTC One m7.
I've got ClockWorkMod Recovery installed and when flashing was done i got stuck in HTC startup screen.
Trying to get in to recovery mode again and install my backup did not work, it just shows ClockWorkMod Recovery logo and reboots.

Is there any way to use ADB/fastboot when in the bootloader screen?

**Info from bootloader screen:**

- M7_UL PVT SHIP S-ON RH
- HBOOT-1.56.0000
- RADIO-4A.23.3263.28
- OpenDSP-V32.120.274.0909
- OS-4.19.401.8
- eMMC-boot 2048MB

Comment: Have you tried to make a factory reset via ClockworkMod and wipe cache, dalvik, etc.?

Comment: You should be able to use `fastboot` while in bootloader mode to flash the correct CWM version.  Is that not working for you?

Comment: @Bewn: Please don't edit "Solved" into the title – instead, upvote/accept the answer which solved your issue (as you answered your question yourself, you will be able to "accept" in within 48h – but cannot upvote it). This is not a forum, but a "question-and-answer" (Q&A) site, which works a little different ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first problem was that fastboot didn't connect to my PC.
This was solved by changing computer to one with a USB 2.0.

The problem I had with my recovery was solved by flashing the recovery partition again and cleaning the cache (forget that the first time).

```
fastboot flash recovery clockworkrec.img
fastboot erase cache
```

After this I was able to get into recovery mode.

I then had a problem where Android Revolution HD did not install and my HTC One M7 was stuck in a bootloop.

This was solved by installing TWRP instead of CWM recovery, and by changing S-ON to S-OFF.
I was then able to install Android Revolution HD.

*Thanks for the comments and many thanks to "bored_stupid" on XDA-Developers who solved the installation problem for me.*